# Porting a view hierarchy from ember-0.9.8.1 to ember-1.0.0-rc.6

Tags: ember.js

I can not get my head around this. I have started from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBmUs/63/) (a showcase for image preview + upload), which is working with `ember-0.9.8.1`, and I am trying to get it working with `ember-1.0.0-rc.6` in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufosEYO/2/).

This is the relevant part causing problems:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Ember.View contentBinding="App.myModel"}}
      {{#view App.PreviewUploadImage name="logo_image" contentBinding="content"}}
        {{view fileField}}
        {{view previewImageView width="200" height="100" srcBinding="content.myModel_src"}}
      {{/view}}
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

Together with this js:

```
App.PreviewUploadImage = Ember.View.extend({
    fileField: Ember.TextField.extend({...}),
});
```

As you can see in the console errors:

```
Assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'fileField'
Assertion failed: You must pass a view to the #view helper, not fileField () 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'proto' of undefined
```

But `fileField` is a `Ember.TextField` (so indeed a view) and is defined in the context where it is used (the view `PreviewUploadImage`).

So where is the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem you are running into is due to the fact that the `fileField` view is not created automatically so the lookup fails.

Try to create the view instead of extending:

```
App.PreviewUploadImage = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  childViews: ['fileField'],
  fileField: Ember.TextField.create({...}),
});
```

### Update

edited my answer I forgot something substantial, to make the outer view a `ContainerView` and define `fileField` as a child view in the `childViews` array.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not solving the problem. :(

Comment: @gonvaled, sorry, forgot something important... have a look now

Comment: Thanks, that is correct: `ContainerView` and `childViews` do the trick. `create` is not really needed. Here the working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufosEYO/3). Is `ContainerView` a new concept? (I am not managing to keep up with development of ember.js)

Comment: @gonvaled, not at all, `ContainerView` exists for a while now. But you are right, keeping up with ember.js can be sometimes a full-time job :)

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not reference the view, but your controller content. You will have to reference the view using `view`, like do this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view Ember.View contentBinding="App.myModel"}}
    {{#view App.PreviewUploadImage name="logo_image" contentBinding="content"}}
      {{view view.fileField}}
      {{view view.previewImageView width="200" height="100" srcBinding="content.myModel_src"}}
    {{/view}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was a typo (I am trying several things). `view.fileField` can indeed be used, but it is not really needed (`fileField` is enough). The solution is the one provided by intuitivepixel.